# Fill by group is not showing up in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a stacked 100% area chart showing the distribution of two rider types (casual vs member) from hours between 0 and 24. However, my plot does not show up with separate fills for my group.

My table is the following:

```
start_hour_dist <- clean_trips  %>%
  group_by(start_hour, member_casual) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(percentage = n / sum(n))
```

[start_hour_dist table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsm9U.png)

my code for the plot is the following:

```
ggplot(start_hour_dist, mapping = aes(x=start_hour, y=percentage, fill=member_casual)) + 
  geom_area()
```

However, when I run the plot, my chart does not have the fill and looks like this:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYGeW.png)

What can I do to make the plot show up something like this?
[image from r-graph-gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr9v9.png)

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). To share your data use e.g. `dput()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely the `start_hour` column being passed as a character vector. Change to an integer first. For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(start_hour = sprintf("%02d", rep(0:23, each = 2)),
       member_casual = rep(c("member", "casual"), times = 24),
       percentage = runif(48)) 




df |> 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(
    x = start_hour,
    y = percentage,
    fill = member_casual
  )) +
  geom_area()
```

This re-creates your blank graph:

[image]

Changing the column type first:

```r
df |> 
  mutate(start_hour = as.integer(start_hour)) |> 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(
    x = start_hour,
    y = percentage,
    fill = member_casual
  )) +
  geom_area(position = "fill")
```

[image]